# Как отличить наречие от вводного?

Tags: вводные-слова

Он предположительно хотел напасть на обидчика с ножом.

Или же:

Он, предположительно, хотел напасть на обидчика с ножом.

"Предположительно" - наречие или вводное?

Один из них мы можем реконструировать лишь предположительно. Здесь нет сомнений: это наречие.

Каждый немецкий лейтенант, взглянув на карту, где были предположительно помечены места скопления русских войск, мог расшифровать высшую военно-государственную тайну Советской России, известную лишь Сталину, Жукову, Василевскому.

Были помечены (как?) предположительно. Тоже понятно.

Из рудника в Саганде, где предположительно урана 1400 тонн.

Здесь предположительно, наверное, не может быть наречием, так как наречия не  относятся к существительным. И это слово относится, наверное, к пропущенному сказуемому.

Тогда правильно будет:

Из рудника в Саганде, где, предположительно, урана 1400 тонн. (Предположительно - вводное. Можно заменить вводным "возможно".)

Answer (score 5):

Он, предположительно, хотел напасть на обидчика с ножом. Это однозначно вводное слово.

Он хотел напасть на обидчика предположительно с ножом. Это наречие, отнесенное к предложному сочетанию.

Из рудника в Саганде, где, предположительно, урана 1400 тонн. Из рудника в Саганде, где урана предположительно 1400 тонн.

В приведенных примерах функция слова  "предположительно"  задается структурой предложения.